# replaceAll repeats characters

Tags: java, regex

For some reason the I get this output

pass : 12345

port : 8080

cookie : not found

host : localhost

**passwordword : 12345**

*When I want*

pass : 12345

port : 8080

cookie : not found

host : localhost

**password : 12345**

```
  public static String modifyString(String str) {
    if (str.matches("(.*)=($)")){
        str = str.replace("=", " : not found");
    } else {
        str = str.replace("=", " : ");
    }
    return str;
}

            if (arr[i] != null){
            if (arr[i].contains("pass")) {
                arr[arr.length - 1] = arr[i];
                arr[arr.length -1] = arr[i].replaceAll("pass", "password");
                System.out.println(modifyString(arr[i]));

            } else {
                System.out.println(modifyString(arr[i]));
            }
```

Comment: password : 12345 and not passwordword : 12345

Comment: You take the word `password` and asking to replace `pass` with `password`.  Would do you expect?

Comment: What I am trying to do is replace the word pass, with the word password, at the last array index.

Comment: You are not replacing a **word** `pass`, you are replacing a **string**.

Comment: what is the target string, do note seet it

Comment: try `(?<=\bpass\b)` with `word`

Comment: @Edward What does this even means: (?<=\bpass\b)?

Comment: it a look behind assershun turns this `pass here password` into `password here password`

Comment: @Edward:  I think `\bpass\b` (word boundary from both ends) should be enough.

Comment: heh, many ways do it. replace `\bpass\b ` with `password` is also goode

Answer (score 0):

You trying to process the string “password”. replaceAll(“pass”, “password”) replaces the “pass” to the “password” and keeps the trailing “word”. So the result is for sure must be “passwordword”.

Comment: So how should this be handled? Trying to learn string manipulation.

Comment: If you want to match only the word “pass” you can use various escaping characters before and after that word like \b - word boundary or \s - space character.

Answer (score 0):

Since replaceAll("pass", "password") matches "**pass**word" you get "**password**word".

To solve this a simple solution is to use a regular expression:

```
string.replaceAll("\\bpass\\b", "password");
```

This would cause it to only match the word "pass" and not do partial matches.

More documentation on this can be found in the **Pattern** class of the Javadocs or for more examples see this article:

https://howtodoinjava.com/regex/java-regex-specific-contain-word/